# Select shifted column values based on a different column conditional in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
A     B
100   0.00
50   -0.50
100   1.00
120   0.20
```

I would like to select shifted values on the A column based on a certain condition on the B column, so for instance if B >= 0.20 and my desired shift step is 2 I would get 100 (from B =1.00) and 50 (from B = 0.20 ), rows where B < 0.20 can be discarded.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Do you have multiple shift values you need to implement in some sort of `if-else` logic? Or are we just leaving anything <0.2 `NaN`?

Comment: @ALollz: Not interested in those rows, they could be NaN's or left out ( but I can do that later on a new  df I suppose), edited the question, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift` with `np.where` to conditionally get the shifted values:

```
shiftstep = 2

df['shift'] = np.where(df['B'].ge(0.2), df['A'].shift(shiftstep), np.NaN)
```

---

```
     A    B  shift
0  100  0.0    NaN
1   50 -0.5    NaN
2  100  1.0  100.0
3  120  0.2   50.0
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I wasn't aware of the ge operator...https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html

Comment: Note: It turns out that I also needed the opposite selection, using a negative`'shiftstep` works !